# Recursively swapping list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, integer

The below code works on a call like this:

```
print((swap_elements('dog'))
```

but not:

```
print((swap_elements[1,2,3,4]))
```

which should print:

```
[2,1,4,3]
```

The error I get is a type error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'. That makes sense, I just don't know enough about Python to know how to deal with different types like this. Please note in this particular it must be recursive, and I cannot use built-in functions besides len, str, append, int.

Any ideas/explanation would be very helpful! Thank you.

```
def swap_elements(elements):

   if len(elements) >= 2:
        return elements[1] + elements[0] + 
        swap_elements(elements[2:])

   return elements
```

Comment: The problem is not that you have integers inside the list, but that you have a list instead of a string. For a string, `elements[0]` gives you a string, because Python does not have a separate type to represent individual letters. But for a list, `elements[0]` gives you one of the things contained within the list - *not* a single-item list wrapping that thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do list concatenation only with lists, so change

```
elements[1] + elements[0] + swap_elements(elements[2:])
```

to

```
[elements[1]] + [elements[0]] + swap_elements(elements[2:])
```

Comment: Ohh interesting, makes sense! Thanks so much!